# npx license mit > LICENSE throwing an error. 'license' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npx

I'm using this chain of commands to initialize a new Node project:

```
npx license mit > LICENSE
npx gitignore node
npx covgen YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
npm init -y
```

Everything works except for the first line: `npx license mit > LICENSE`

I'm getting the following error:
`'license' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Do I need to set anything additional up to get the command to spit out a MIT license for me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the `npx license mit` generates the file automatically
no need to specify the redirect file

Comment: Even without the redirect it still doesn't work. I get: `'license' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: then try `npm i license -g` then `license mit` or `npx license mit`

Comment: Additionally, on Windows at least, the license type needs to be uppercase, so you need `npx license MIT`

Comment: I can also confirm that `npx license` does not work out-of-the-box on Windows, but if you first do `npm i -g license` and then follow up with `npx license MIT` then you get the results you expect, however that seems to defeat the purpose of `npx` doesn't it?

Comment: it doesn't defeat the purpose exactly, since its main purpose is to "excute" commands, however that might means one of its features is broken, maybe try using a different version of npm to see where the problem is ?